# chart.js 'Chart' is not defined no-undef

Tags: javascript, chart.js

i ran my program in node.js localhost but it has an error. I have already install npm chart.js
./src/index.js
Line 2:  'Chart' is not defined  no-undef

In my index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

In my index.js:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried your code and it is all working : [https://jsfiddle.net/markwan/5n3q7xoz/](https://jsfiddle.net/markwan/5n3q7xoz/)

Comment: the graph is shown at the first moment but in the second moment it suddenly jump into Line 2:19:  'Chart' is not defined  no-undef in my localhost live server

Comment: i dont know whether is my package json is incorrect since its copy from somewhere

Comment: What environment you are developing ? If you can edit your question & code precisely, I can help you with that

Comment: i want to develop my program in node js server

Comment: You should use your chart.js on client side with html & JS code, then you can ajax to get data from your node.js server.

Comment: Your config and chart version dont match, you are using v3 syntax while using v2 from cdn, either change your chart version or use these docs to configure your chart: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/